# Update table mysql and if value is 10 update another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following sql to update results table:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE results
                SET result_value = IF('$logo_value' - result_tries < 0 OR '$logo_value' - result_tries = 0, 1, '$logo_value' - result_tries)
                WHERE logo_id = '$logo_id'
                AND user_id = '$user_id'
                AND result_value = 0");
```

In the same sql command is it possible to update another table based on result_value?

```
if result_value = 10
Update users SET user_hints = user_hints +1 WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
```

How would I incorporate this into sql syntax above?

Long way I can think of is to select this value get it into php variable. And than do another update based on php variable value... But this seems long and tedious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot (not tested) but how about:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE results, users
                SET result_value = 
                        IF('$logo_value' - results.result_tries < 0 OR 
                           '$logo_value' - results.result_tries = 0, 
                            1, '$logo_value' - result_tries),
                    users.user_hints = 
                        IF(results.result_value >= 10, 
                           users.user_hints + 1, users.user_hints)
                WHERE results.logo_id = '$logo_id'
                AND results.user_id = '$user_id'
                AND results.user_id = users.user_id
                AND results.result_value = 0");
```

If both tables have some of the same column names, of course, youll have to specify which table (like `results.user_id` -or- `users.user_id`)

Comment: In this case WHERE AND AND is applied to only results table?